# How to check on every request a user status (and redirect to it)

Tags: symfony

I'm making a "browser game" in Symfony2 (like an RPG). There's a moment when you start a battle, and you can't do anything else until the battle is over.

I need to check, when a user have an status like "In battle" wherever URL he is trying to reach, redirect to the "battle page".

I tried with an EventListener to Kernel.Request, and check every time when that user have the BATTLE status AND is not in the Battle Page redirect there. That doesn't work well because I have a lot of request and things I have to exclude like DebuggerToolbar, etc..

There's a proper way to do this? Maybe special add an special role/permission? Check on every controller? in the action?

I'm sure there's a good way to do this but I don't know how to look for it.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by listening to the `kernel.controller` event and throw an error when the condition is not met to execute that controller with a specific exception.

Create an exception listener that will execute the redirect when intercepts that specific exception.

A very good description of the mechanism you can read here: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/12/prevent-controller-execution-with-annotations-and-return-a-custom-response/